# How to convert month-yyyy text column to date column in SQL Server 2008

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, type-conversion

I have a text column which has month year data in it (Example: APR17). The first 3 letters are always the month and the last two digits are the year. I would like to convert this text column to the last date of that month in date format (so APR17 = 2017-04-30). I have SQL Server 2008, `EOMONTH` is not a recognized function in it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SQL Server is pretty good about figuring out what dates look like when doing conversions.  I think this works:

```
select cast('01' + mmmyy as date)
```

You could also transform the string to a recognized format for `convert()`, but the above is simpler.

And for the last day of the month:

```
select dateadd(day, -1, dateadd(month, 1, cast('01' + mmmyy as date)))
```

Comment: Thanks for the quicky reply, it works.  The part B is how to to convert that to last date of the month

Comment: you can use `select DATEADD(DAY,-1,DATEADD(MONTH,1,CONVERT(DATE, '01'+mmmyy )))`

Comment: Perfect, That is exactly what I am looking for.  Thank you